# Check DHCP Option content

Tags: linux, dhcp, options

Is it possible DHCP client check the contents of an option ?

I need provisioning a Linux server with DHCP option 140 (option-140).

But the server behaves as if the DHCP did not contain the information.

In the file /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases

I do not see advanced DHCP options (option-140, option-141, option-142).

How can I manually request the DHCP server to give me the contents of an option (to control the content)?

Answer (score 2):

1. Fire up `tcpdump` or `tshark` on eth0... look for all UDP packets and make your sniffer give verbose output (see manpage)
2. `sudo dhclient -r`
3. `sudo dhclient`